# Integrating Microsoft Universal Ad Client SDK to native win32 desktop app

Tags: xaml, win-universal-app, uwp

Is it possible to integrate Microsoft Universal Ad Client SDK to a native win32 app?

Does the Ad SDK work also in Win7 or Win8?

I am looking for a solution such as making a small EXE that I call from my application, that will simply display video ads and then quit.

Answer (score 0):

if you're targeting Windows 8 and up, I would suggest to create a Windows Store app hosting the Ad control and launch this app using a custom protocol

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/Hh779670(v=win.10).aspx

As an example, try to run (Windows+R) this on Windows 8 :

bingmaps:?q=restaurant&where=Paris

Answer (score 0):

Universal SDK can only be referenced on Universal Apps.

As you are asking how to integrate a such SDK on a native Win32 app, you should look for an Ad SDK for native app.